# Is it possible to forward only part of a path using aws elb?

Tags: amazon-elb

I am trying to create rules in my ALB so there are parts of the path that I do not forward on to the target.  So for example, my underlying service may accept a call like

GET http://hostname/dogs

But in the ALB I might add a version to the path for routing purposes:

GET http://hostname/v1/dogs

or I could call

GET http://hostname/v2/dogs

Both versions would be running in different target groups.  I was thinking I could then drop the version part off so that my application doesn't have to be concerned with versioning.  However, it's not obvious how I might handle that and it doesn't appear to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that is currently supported by Application Load Balancer.

CloudFront, however, has a setting called [Origin Path](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath) that is prepended to the request URI before sending the request to the origin server -- in this case, the origin ALB -- so you'd set the origin path to `/v1` if you wanted `example.com/dogs` to be sent to the ALB as `example.com/v1/dogs`.  CloudFront is a CDN but it has a number of other purposes, such as request rewriting -- it's essentially a massive, globally-distributed reverse proxy with a cache, and supports dynamic as well as static content.  More complex rewrites require Lambda@Edge in addition to CloudFront, but prepending a string to certain request path patterns is part of the base feature set.

Comment: So, for this we keep using ALB but we add CloudFront?